# Why Does Excel 2010 Leave A Trail Of TMP Files?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-excel, files

I am losing hard drive space because of some deep, dark phenomenon being caused by Excel 2010.  It seems like every time a user opens or closes a file, or maybe if Excel crashes (I haven't figured out which), a fairly sizable TMP file (usually around the size of the original) is left behind and never cleared out by Excel.  The filename is usually a 6-8_digit_number.TMP or a combination of the original_file_name_plus_some-hex.TMP.

Comment: I've seen this issue before, and never really put much time into solving it.  It seemed at the time to be linked to the place we were serving files.  We tested serving files from another server and the issue didn't follow the files/users over there.

Comment: Are the .tmp files in the same folder as the actual file? Could it be that new Office 2010 thingy which saves stuff even when you tell it not to? Finally, Microsoft have learnt to not trust the user and do the exact opposite when you say "No, I *REALLY* don't want to save this file" :-)

Comment: Yes, residing in the same directory.  It's seeming like they're files being created when Excel crashes, as in joeqwerty's answer candidate below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Excel (or any other Microsoft Office product) crashes, that would be the expected behavior.

Comment: Then I'm getting a lot of crashes.  Maybe I should be asking why would Excel be crashing so much.  And why the 2 different types of file names?